# Разница statlesswidget и stateful

Tags: flutter, dart

Я начинающий программист
Не могу понять разницы, они всегда друг друга включают? Как это работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**StatelessWidget** – рекомендуется для неизменяемых виджетов. Это такие виджеты которые не имеют внутреннего состояния, зависят только от конфигурационных параметров и от родительских виджетов.

Вот некоторые виджеты которые наследуются от StatelessWidget:

```
Text()
FlatButton()
Container()
и др.
```

Самая простая конструкция для создания виджета от суперкласса StatelessWidget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('my text');
  }
}
```

**StatelessWidget** – нужен там где внутреннее состояние одно и оно сформировано параметрами и данными которые нам известны заранее.

---

**StatefulWidget** – рекомендуется для изменяемых виджетов, с изменяемым внутренним состоянием (State). Под изменяемым состоянием понимается изменение внутреннего состояния экземпляра класса в зависимости от какого-то события (по нажатию, времени и пр.) Для этого нужно создавать виджет котопый наследует StatefulWidget.

Вот некоторые виджеты, которые наследуются от StatefulWidget:

```
Image()
Form()
и др.
```

Самая простая конструкция для создания виджета от суперкласса StatefulWidget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('my text');
  }
}
```

**StatefulWidget** – нужен когда внутренних состояний больше одного и они могут сменять друг друга.

---

*Создатели Flutter рекомендуют использовать **StatelessWidget** везде, где можно обойтись без **StatefulWidget**. Это связано с тем что перестроение **StatefulWidget** стоит намного дороже (в плане потребления ресурсов и отрисовки). Так же рекомендуется сводить к минимуму дочерних виджетов в **StatefulWidget**.*

---

*[Источник](https://flutter.su/tutorial/2-StatelessWidget-StatefulWidget)*

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в производительности.

`StatelessWidget` - этот виджет используется, когда данные внтури него не предполагают изменений. Т.е. он, и все что внутри него, создается 1 раз. Если же Вы, захотите каким-то образом поменять данные внутри него - то по сути, этот виджет будет пересоздаваться, т.е. это будет уже другой виджет

`StatefulWidget` - соответственно, наоборот. Используется тогда, когда данные внутри него, в период его существования, предполагают изменения.