# как изменять текст с помощью onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart

***0) вопрос*** Как получить доступ к виджету, что бы изменить в нем текст, например аналог идентификатора или ключ?

***1) вопрос*** Как правильно использовать событие **onPressed** ?

```
onPressed: () => {
 f1()
}
```

или присваиваем ему ссылку на метод

```
onPressed: f1
```

или в самом событии пишем код

```
onPressed: () => {
 switch(b) {
   case true:
    str = 'True';
    b = false;
    break;
   case false:
    str = 'False';
    b = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

***2) вопрос*** не получается изменять текст при нажатии на кнопку.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 String str = 'Yes';
 bool b = false;

 //метод должен меняет текст
 void f1() {
  switch(b) {
   case true:
    str = 'True';
    b = false;
    break;
   case false:
    str = 'False';
    b = true;
    break;
  }
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
       child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         CupertinoButton(
          onPressed: () => {
           f1()
          },
          //onPressed: f1,
          color: Colors.orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          child: Text(
           'Ok',
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
         ),
         Text(
          //здесь должен меняться текст после нажатия кнопки
          str,
         )
        ],
       ),
      ),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Только изучаю Flutter, пытаюсь разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, необходимо узнать что такое StatelessWidget и StatefulWidget ([и какая между ними разница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1057586/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-statlesswidget-%D0%B8-stateful/1057725#1057725)).

> StatelessWidget – это такие виджеты которые не имеют внутреннего
>   состояния, зависят только от конфигурационных параметров и от
>   родительских виджетов.
>
> StatefulWidget – рекомендуется для изменяемых виджетов, с изменяемым
>   внутренним состоянием.

Исходя из этого мы понимаем: чтобы изменить данные внутри **StatelessWidget**, необходимо создать конструктор этого класса с необходимыми для нас полями. Пример:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final text;
  MyWidget(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

При вызове `MyWidget("...")` текст будет меняться. Но если вам необходимо изменять ваши данные без ручного участия (с использованием внутреннего состояния), например при нажатии на кнопку, то следует использовать **StatefulWidget**. Для примера возьмём ваш код:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String str;
  bool b;

  // Вызывается один раз при инициализации виджета
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    str = 'Yes';
    b = false;
  }

  void f1() {
    switch (b) {
      case true:
        str = 'True';
        b = false;
        break;
      case false:
        str = 'False';
        b = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                // setState() обозначает что наше состояние изменилось => необходимо
                // перестроить виджет для отображения новых данных.
                onPressed: () => {setState(() => f1())},
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Text(
                  'Ok',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Text(str),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Напоследок соединим два примера в один:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// 1 пример
class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final text;
  MyText(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new MyWidgetState();
}

// 2 пример
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String str;
  bool b;

  // Вызывается один раз при инициализации виджета
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    str = 'Yes';
    b = false;
  }

  void f1() {
    switch (b) {
      case true:
        str = 'True';
        b = false;
        break;
      case false:
        str = 'False';
        b = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                // setState() обозначает что наше состояние изменилось => необходимо
                // перестроить виджет для отображения новых данных.
                onPressed: () => {setState(() => f1())},
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Text(
                  'Ok',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              // Вызов 1 примера
              MyText(str),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Ответ на 0 вопрос**:

```
void main() {
  Person p1 = new Person();
  p1.age = 1;
  print(p1.age);
}

class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  Person({this.name, this.age});
}
```

**Ответ на 1 вопрос**: обычно используют либо 1 либо 3 вариант, выбор между ними: от количества кода (если 1-2 строчки можно и 3 вариант выбрать. Если больше, то 1).

---

*Если у Вас остались вопросы, я с удовольствием на них отвечу.*

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо! А вот 0) вопрос. Есть ли доступ к виджетам по аналогии id, как в JavaScript или Android Kotlin? Спасибо.

Comment: @Anton можно привести пример? Я просто не особо понимаю что имеется ввиду...

Comment: Text(
id: t1
//или
key: 't1'
str,
)

//button
onPressed: () => {
 t1.str = 'Привет Мир!'
}

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, id нет точно, а вот с key еще не разобрался. Просто может быть большая вложенность, что бы не перерисовывать большое количество виджетов, а точечно решить задачу.

Comment: @Anton обновил ответ, посмотрите это вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @Anton информация по key's: https://habr.com/ru/post/446050/

Comment: Не совсем. Это объект класса.

Comment: @Anton можете привести ссылку примера на Kotlin'е?