# FLUTTER: Двойное пересоздание виджет StateFull -> Build

Tags: flutter

Как (можно ли) устранить двойное создание виджета Widget build(BuildContext context)?

Классическая структура есть класс от StatefullWidget

```
class BodyView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyViewState createState() => _BodyViewState();
}
```

И есть тело в котором переопределен initState (Добавленна загрузка _loadSelect() из SharedPreferences значения selectPage с setState()-ом)

```
class _BodyViewState extends State<BodyView> {
  int selectedPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadSelect();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Получается что Widget создается до выполнения метода initState(и пытается вывести себя на экран, при этом значение selectedPage не определено). После чего выполняется initState и еще раз запускает пересоздание Widget-а.

Пробовал через Future сделать - аналогичная ситуация. Что я не правильно делаю? Или как правильно. Или это проблема Flutter-а и её не исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Или это проблема Flutter-а и её не исправить?

В первую очередь это не понимание как работает Flutter. Для начала я рекомендую прочитать про [разницу между StatlessWidget и StatefulWidget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1057725/261617), а также [как работает асинхронность в Flutter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013829/261617).

---

### Ответ на ваш изначальный вопрос:

В `initState` вы запускаете асинхронную функцию (то есть не блокируете дальнейшие построение `widget`, что является правильным), далее `widget` строиться, но без значения `selectedPage` (что скорее всего и дает ошибку). После чего `_loadSelect` завершает свою работу и вызывает `setState`, тем самым вызывая перестроение `widget` уже во второй раз.

Чтобы не перестраивать весь `widget` можно использовать [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), он будет сам следить и вызывать перестроение внутри себя когда асинхронная операция будет завершаться. Но это не освобождает вас от того, что на момент когда асинхронная операция выполняется вам нужно что-то показать пользователю (лоадер и т.д.).

Либо использовать `State Management`: `Redux`, `BLoC`, `MobX`...

---

*`Widget` **никогда не создается** до выполнения метода `initState`*

Comment: Спасибо. Именно так я себе и представил эту проблему. Если я правильно понимаю, лучше всего  при первом построении оставить `selectPage = null(или другой неиспользуемой величине)`, а при формировании `widget` отловить это состояние и показать `loader` вместо одной из реальных страниц. Мелькание лоадера будет оправдано. В моем варианте от выбора в `BottomTabBar` меняется основное наполнение экрана. Еще раз спасибо. И за наводку про другие паттерны. Почитаю, может перейду на них.

Comment: @Andrey Всегда пожалуйста!) Да, без `loader'a` в современной разработки не обойтись) _Если мой ответ вам помог, его можно пометь как решение (галочка), с правой стороны под стрелочками._